# change data-unknown attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have page with 3  divs each div has 2 data-attribute for example

```
<div class="div1" data-10="some value" data-30="some value"></div>
```

i can change the value of the data attribute by this method

```
 $('.div1').attr('data-30', 'some changed values');
```

but the problem is that the second part of the data attribute is unknown (data-unknown number)

i don't know the number after this sign "`-`" it may will be `30,40,50 or what ever` so how can i select the data attribute that i want to change it's value ?

i only want to change the second data-attribute , i don't care about the first one

how can i do it ?

big thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of calling it `data-[num]` why don't you just call it `data-unknown` and target it. I mean it sounds like the name isn't relevant, just the value, so it doesn't matter what the name is ultimately.

Comment: There is something wrong here. Why a `data-*` attribute should be "unknown"?

Comment: @Vohuman  the data-* is unknown because this number is changeable depends on the width and the height of the screen , i am using it for parallax approach

Comment: That should be a value not a key. Doesn't using `data-height` or `data-width` make more sense?

Comment: @Vohuman no i must use data-number and to make it responsive the number is not unknown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit, Updated

> still doesn't change the value of the data-attr

jQuery `.data()` does not change `data-*` attributes , see [jQuery's .data() doesn't append attribute to DOMElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766984/jquerys-data-doesnt-append-attribute-to-domelement) , [jQuery Data vs Attr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr) .

Try utilizing [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) (ie11) to set actual `html` `dataset` , e.g.,

```
elem[0].dataset[key] = "margin-top:100px";
```

> only want to change the second data-attribute , i don't care about the
>   first one

Try utilizing `.data()` , `$.map()`

```js
var index = 0, elem = $(".div1");
$.map(elem.data(), function(value, key) {
  ++index;
  // if `index` is `2`
  if (index === 2) {
    // do stuff with second `data-*` attribute
    // change the value of that data-attribute
    // for example to `margin-top:100px`
    elem.data(key, "margin-top:100px");
    // still doesn't change the value of the data-attr
    elem[0].dataset[key] = "margin-top:100px";
  }
});

console.log(elem.data(), elem[0].dataset["30"]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div1" data-10="some value" data-30="some value"></div>
```

Comment: that's exactly what i want but could you please give me an example of how to change the value of that data-attribute for example to `margin-top:100px`

Comment: @user2976078  _"that's exactly what i want but could you please give me an example of how to change the value of that data-attribute for example to `margin-top:100px`"_ See updated post.

Comment: still doesn't change the value of the data-attr

Comment: @user2976078 _"still doesn't change the value of the data-attr"_ ? Can create jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Is requirement to change actual `html` `data-*` attribute ? , not jQuery `.data()` object ?

Comment: @guest271314: Note that `elem.data(key, "margin-top:100px")` doesn't change the attribute (and using `data` for this is very inefficient, as I called out in my answer when showing how to do it).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder _"Note that elem.data(key, "margin-top:100px") doesn't change the attribute"_ Yes, see updated post. Was not certain if jQuery `.data()` object or `HTMLElement.dataset` was used to process `data-*` attribute , see updated post

Comment: @user2976078: Just note, again, that this is *really inefficient*. In the above, it also relies on `dataset`, [for which support is quite spotty](http://caniuse.com/#feat=dataset). Recommend A) Not using jQuery for this, it's massive overkill; and B) If you do, use `attr`, not `dataset`, to update the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

First, I must agree with Vohuman: I wouldn't do this, I'd change the name to something consistent. I'm not seeing why you have to do this to make it responsive, since you can use not just attributes but their **values** in CSS, e.g.:

```
[data-width="100"] {
    /* Rules here */
}
```

But answering the question you actually asked:

Two Options:

#### Use the DOM

The DOM provides an [`attributes` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-84CF096) for getting all of the attributes on an element:

```
var attrs = $(".div1")[0].attributes;    // [0] = Get the raw element
```

(Obviously, if you need to do this to all matching elements, use a loop and index rather than `0` directly.)

It's a [`NamedNodeMap`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-1780488922) that you can loop through:

```
var i, attr;
for (i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i) {
    attr = attrs[i];
    if (/^data-\d+$/.test(attr.nodeName)) { // regex matches `data-nnn` where
                                            // nnn is a number of any number of digits
        // This is the attribute, change it
        attr.nodeValue = theNewValue;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var attrs = $(".div1")[0].attributes; // [0] = Get the raw element
var i, attr;
for (i = 0; i < attrs.length; ++i) {
  attr = attrs[i];
  if (/^data-\d+$/.test(attr.nodeName)) { // regex matches `data-nnn` where
    // nnn is a number of any number of digits
    // This is the attribute, change it
    snippet.log("The attribute was: " + attr.nodeName);
    attr.nodeValue = "the new value";
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" data-10="foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you use ES5 methods in your environment (you don't have to support really old browsers or you use a shim for them), we can make that a *tiny* bit more concise but quite possibly less clear:

```
Array.prototype.some.call($(".div1")[0].attributes, function(attr) {
  if (/^data-\d+$/.test(attr.nodeName)) { // regex matches `data-nnn` where
                                          // nnn is a number of any number of digits
    // This is the attribute, change it
    snippet.log("The attribute was: " + attr.nodeName);
    attr.nodeValue = "the new value";
    return true;
  }
});
```

```js
Array.prototype.some.call($(".div1")[0].attributes, function(attr) {
  if (/^data-\d+$/.test(attr.nodeName)) { // regex matches `data-nnn` where
    // nnn is a number of any number of digits
    // This is the attribute, change it
    snippet.log("The attribute was: " + attr.nodeName);
    attr.nodeValue = "the new value";
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="div1" data-10="foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

#### Use jQuery's `data` to figure out the name, then `attr` to change it

Note: This is inefficient.

jQuery's `data` method will return an object that is initialized from all of the `data-*` attributes. So you can get that object, loop through its property names, and find the name that corresponds.

```
var div = $(".div1");
var data = div.data();
var name;
for (name in data) {
  if (/^\d+$/.test(name) && data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    // This is it
    div.attr("data-" + name, "the new value");
    break;
  }
}
```

This will not work if the names have other thing after the digits, such as `data-10-foo-bar`, because jQuery converts `dashed-names` into `camelCase`.

Why this is inefficient:

1. jQuery just has to do the `attributes` thing to build the data object
2. It then *stores* the data object in its cache of data for that element

So on the whole, I wouldn't do it this way.

**Live Example:**

```js
var div = $(".div1");
var data = div.data();
var name;
for (name in data) {
  if (/^\d+$/.test(name) && data.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
    // This is it
    snippet.log("The attribute was data-" + name);
    div.attr("data-" + name, "the new value");
    break;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="div1" data-10="foo"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: i can't use fixed names because the name depends on the height of the screen , also the value of the data-attribute will not be the same every time, that's why i am looking for solution , i think your jQuery solution would work for me , thank you :)